# Accurate running time in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have DateTimePicker on my form and I want it to only display TIME
I use the code below to do that and it worked

```
dtpTimeIn.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
dtpTimeIn.Value = DateTime.Now;
dtpTimeIn.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Now my problem is, I want it to be a running time wherein the seconds is continuously running
I used DateTime.Now but it's not working

Please help me to find another solution

Comment: Do you mean you want a Timer that ticks every second and sets `dtpTimeIn.Value = DateTime.Now;`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do

Comment: You have a `Timer` Component in the Toolbox

Comment: Yes I have that. I already did it on a label and it worked

Comment: timer1.Start();
            lbTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

Comment: But I can't do it on the DateTimePicker

Comment: Then why do you want it with a DateTimePicker?

Comment: What does that mean? Did you subscribe to the `Tick` event of the Timer and set the `dtpTimeIn.Value` in the Tick event handler? In your comment, the text of a Label is set just once, after you start the Timer, but you don't say what happens when the Timer Ticks

Comment: Because what I'm doing is a parking lot system, and I want it to the "Vehicle IN" to be the exact time as default when clicked, and I also want it to be editable

Comment: If you need to show the current Time, to the second, what is the *editing* for?  Can't you just take the current time?

Comment: https://youtu.be/1d4VU8cCRLQ

Comment: Check out this vid

Comment: This is what Im trying to do

Comment: You can't reasonable allow the user to edit the value when you update it once a second.  Technically you could suppress the update when the DTP has the focus, but that will happen a lot.  Keep the label, use the DTP only for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Here's my VB example. The seconds/time updates every timer1.tick.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        dtpTimeIn.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time
        dtpTimeIn.Value = DateTime.Now
        dtpTimeIn.ShowUpDown = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        dtpTimeIn.Value = DateTime.Now

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I just forgot to add it to Timer_Tick